# Is it okay if the Power LED to flash once while switching on UPS?

Tags: motherboard, power, led

My CPUs front panel power LED is flashing once after I powered on the UPS.
A 'TUCK' sound is also coming from my speakers.
Is that normal or is there any issue with my motherboard?

Comment: ...with your powersupply.

Comment: What UPS do you have? Also, a power supply usually also have a power switch on the back that you can turn off. I would strongly advise doing that before turning on the ups.

Comment: I Have Zebronics ZEB-U725 UPS. I dont have a switch in SMPS.

Comment: Does it do it without the ups?

Comment: Yes, I check it. it does